# Static and public positionning

Tags: java, readability, code-readability

I am working with Apache log4j (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) and I realized that in their implementation they always declared their function like this:

```
  static
  public
  Logger getLogger(Class clazz) {
    return LogManager.getLogger(clazz.getName());
  }
```

instead of

```
  static public Logger getLogger(Class clazz) {
    return LogManager.getLogger(clazz.getName());
  }
```

Is there any good reason for using this style?

Comment: it is exactly the same, but I think it makes it easier to discover the visibility of the function and its access level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the [FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a4.2) it says:

> Log4j has adopted a rather conservative approach **by following the Code
>   Conventions for the JavaTM** Programming Language

However, if you check the examples in the [Java Coding Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-137946.html#186), you find that all the modifiers go on a single line before the function:

```
public void doSomethingElse(Object someParam);
```

If I'd have to guess, I'd say it makes the `diff` easier to spot when committing patches and also maybe avoids long lines.

Answer (score 0):

Different people different coding style... In most cases it is choice of individual to select a way to write the code.

I will personally write signature in one line so that it is more understandable to readable to everyone, and mostly least confusing to others reading my code. :)